# How to use final_embeddings?

Tags: nlp, embedding, python-embedding

From udacity notebook exercise;  After embeddings were trained,  I'm trying to get all related words from an input word and I'm getting wierd results.
Is the code below correct?

[udacity exercise](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/examples/udacity/5_word2vec.ipynb)

```
final_embeddings = normalized_embeddings.eval()
word='history'
nearest = (-final_embeddings[dictionary[word], :]).argsort()[1:9]
for idx in range(len(nearest)):
    print reverse_dictionary[nearest[idx]]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sorry for the dumb question.  Just realized that final_embeddings is the W trained matrix. 
Answer is: given an input word. Similarity is computed doing the prob_vec[word] matmul W

```
word='the'
word_vec = final_embeddings[dictionary[word]]
sim = np.dot(word_vec, -final_embeddings.T).argsort()[0:8]
for idx in range(8):
    print reverse_dictionary[sim[idx]]
```

Thanks!